# Markov Chains and Conditional Probability: Easy rat in the maze problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

Why is the following solution to this problem incorrect,

> A rat is trapped in a maze with three doors and some hidden cheese. If the rat takes door one, he will wander around the maze for 2 minutes and return to where he started. If he takes door two, he will wander around the maze for 3 minutes and return to where he started. If he takes door three, he will ind the cheese after 1 minute. If the rat returns to where he started he immediately picks a door to pass through. The rat picks each door uniformly at random. How long, on average, will the rat wander before finding the cheese?

1. Construct a graph with three vertices: X, Y, Z, each of which
   represents a door in the original problem.
2. Add edges between every vertex, including self-loops, each of which has a weight of 1/3.
3. Take the stationary distribution to be (1/3, 1/3, 1/3). It is unique because the probability transition question for the graph in (1) is regular (i.e., its limit is just the same matrix with all entries equal to 1/3)
4. Compute the expected time as 2*1/3 + 3*1/3 + 1*1/3 = 2

The correct answer is 6. I know that the set-up is completely wrong and that I should use conditional probability, but is there a way to do it like this? The main issue is that we don't know the total time spent in the maze (this is kind of what we need to find) so I can see that it doesn't really make sense to take this approach.

Comment: I think the third door is an "absorbing" state. It means the end of the game. Since once you visit that state then you will never leave. I do not see why the stationary distribution is $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$.

Answer (score 1):

The rat's sojourn time may be modeled by a Markov chain with transition matrix
$$
P = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Let $Q$ be the matrix whose entries are the expected number of  visits to a transient state starting from another transient state, then since $\|Q\|_1=\sup_{1\leqslant i\leqslant t}\sum_{j=1}^t Q_{ij}=\frac23<1$, the  series
$$
N=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Q^k
$$
converges to $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 3 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
The expected number of steps before being absorbed when starting in a transient state are given by the entries of the vector
$$
\mathbf t = N\mathbf 1 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 8 \\
 10 \\
 11 \\
 9 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
It follows that the expected soujourn time is $8$.